# Clojure - transform flat map to nested with predecided structure

Tags: clojure, hashmap, transformation

I'm a newbie to clojure and i'm trying to convert a messages that come in a particular format into another.

ie, i have to convert something like:

```
   {
     :image-url         ["https://image.png"],
     :topic             "Some title",
     :id                "88ebaf91-a01d-4683-9aa7-629bb3ecea01",
     :short-description "Some Description",
     :mobile-deeplink   "https://deeplink.com/link",
     :partner-name      "partner"}
```

Into something like

```
{
 :title   "Some title",
 :id      "88ebaf91-a01d-4683-9aa7-629bb3ecea01",
 :content {
           :url         ["https://image.png"],
           :description "Some Description",
           :deeplink    "https://deeplink.com/link",
           :partner     "partner"}}
```

So in effect, there is a combination of renaming keys and nesting the flat map

What I have done so far was something on the lines of:

```
(let [message-map {
                   :image-url         :purl
                   :topic             :title
                   :partner-name      :partner
                   :short-description :description
                   :mobile-deeplink   :deeplink}]
  (defn- map-to-body
    [message]
    (-> message
        (clojure.set/rename-keys message-map)
        ;;some sort of (assoc-in) <- this is where i need help in
    )))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining `assoc-in`, a path conversion table, and `reduce` could be more self-describing and maintainable. You could choose to reduce over either the conversion table or the input message, whichever makes more sense for the data you have.

```
(defn transform [m]
  (let [pp '([:image-url [:content :url]]
             [:topic [:title]]
             [:id [:id]]
             [:short-description [:content :description]]
             ;; etc.
             )]
    (reduce
     (fn [o [mk ok]]
       (assoc-in o ok (get m mk)))
     {}
     pp)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could chain-`assoc-in` here, but I think you are easier off
using `select-keys`.  `select-keys` lets you extract only the keys
from a map into a new map, you need.  So you can select `:id`/`:title` for
the outer map and the rest to assoc to `:content`.

E.g.

```clj
(require 'clojure.set)

(defn transform 
  [message]
  (let [message-map {:image-url         :url
                     :topic             :title
                     :partner-name      :partner
                     :short-description :description
                     :mobile-deeplink   :deeplink}
        renamed (clojure.set/rename-keys message message-map)]
    (assoc ; XXX
      (select-keys renamed [:title :id])
      :content (select-keys renamed [:url :description :deeplink :partner]))))

(def src {:image-url         ["https://image.png"],
          :topic             "Some title",
          :id                "88ebaf91-a01d-4683-9aa7-629bb3ecea01",
          :short-description "Some Description",
          :mobile-deeplink   "https://deeplink.com/link",
          :partner-name      "partner"})

(def tgt {:title   "Some title",
          :id      "88ebaf91-a01d-4683-9aa7-629bb3ecea01",
          :content {
                    :url         ["https://image.png"],
                    :description "Some Description",
                    :deeplink    "https://deeplink.com/link",
                    :partner     "partner"}})

(assert  (= (transform src) tgt))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of `select-keys`. Makes sense to do it this way